# Issue With @JsonProperty on Method

Tags: java, json, parsing, annotations, jackson

I currently have my POJO class as such for deserializing a json source.

```
public class OpenBuilding extends Building {

    @JsonProperty("BuildingPostCode")
    @Override
    public String getPostcode() {
        return super.getPostcode();
    }
}
```

Where the parent class is as such

```
public abstract class Buidling {

    protected String postcode;

    public String getPostcode() {
        return this.postcode;
    }
}
```

My issue is that the String postcode isn't getting mapped at all. It works when using the annotation on the field. However since it is an inherited field and I have other children of Building, which use different property names for the same data, I cannot have it implemented in that way.

---

For example:

```
public class DirectedBuilding extends Building {

    @JsonProperty("Pseudo_PostCode")
    @Override
    public String getPostcode() {
        return super.getPostcode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try defining a constructor with `@JsonCreator`.

```
class Parent {

    private final String foo;

    public Parent(final String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    @JsonCreator
    public Child(@JsonProperty("foo") final String foo) {
        super(foo);
    }

    @JsonProperty("foo")
    public String getFoo() {
        return super.getFoo();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final Child toSerialize = new Child("fooValue");

    // Serialize the object to JSON
    final String json = objectMapper.writer()
            .withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .writeValueAsString(toSerialize);

    // Prints { "foo" : "fooValue" }
    System.out.println(json);

    // Deserialize the JSON
    final Child deserializedChild = objectMapper.readValue(json, Child.class);

    // Prints fooValue
    System.out.println(deserializedChild.getFoo());
}
```

Comment: It is useful for this case but becomes less maintainable when I need to do this for 10-20 variables, which some is true for some other classes